# Ruby On Rails deploy in Amazon Web Services - General

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-web-services

I am planning to deploy an application on AWS. It is an application that exposes some REST/Json webservices.
It has a CMS UI created used active_admin.
Can I deploy that system in AWS? Or it is intended to be  used only to deploy webservices systems?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) (which is part of AWS). You can setup a small instance pretty quickly and that should let you deploy your rails application.

Comment: What service does AWS provide that EC2 does not provide?

Comment: AWS is a collection of services. One of them is EC2, another is Route53 (their dns service), another is S3 (storage). You can use EC2 on its own to host a rails site)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Joe's answer, EC2 gives you a virtual server. You can log on the the virtual computer with ssh and install any software you need.

You don't even have to run a web server - if you wanted to run a program to process information (ie, render computer graphics images), you could do that as well.